# Java: Passing classname to function

Tags: java, function, class, refactoring

I have three very similar functions and want to refactor. However, the functions use a function from a class, thus, I wonder if there is a way to pass the class / class name to the function?

```
new GenericClass1 = genericClass1;
new GenericClass2 = genericClass2;
new GenericClass3 = genericClass3;

public ReturnsClass1 myFunction1 (){
    return genericClass1.functionFromClass(paramter);
}
public ReturnsClass2 myFunction2 (){
    return genericClass2.functionFromClass(paramter);
}
public ReturnsClass3 myFunction3 (){
    return genericClass3.functionFromClass(paramter);
}
```

To illustrate I would like something like this:

```
public ReturnsClass myFunction (classInstance) {
    return classInstance.functionFromClass(parameter);
}
```

Comment: Make classes GenericClass1, GenericClass2 and GenericClass3 implement the same interface and your functions accept a parameter of this Iterface type.

Comment: You're not asking your question well, as your question seems to contain it's own answer.  What's the actual problem that you're having?  Some more complete sample code would probably help quite a bit.

Comment: I want to pass the name of a class to a function and use the class within the function. My "solution" is close to what I want, but that code don't work.

Comment: @ArneO.Ose : I've included an answer as well, please do have a look.

Comment: Maybe yor method could accept `java.util.function.Function<T,R>` and bind each generic class’ function to it. Then, inside you just invoke `apply` and use that value. This is how you can avoid implementing interfaces

Answer (score 1):

You can make `GenericClass*` implement a common generic interface, in which the method returns an instance of the generic type parameter.

```
interface GenericInterface<T> {
    T functionName(Object parameter); //change parameter type
}
```

This can then be extended by `GenericClass*`:

```
class GenericClass1 implements GenericInterface<ReturnsClass1> {
    public ReturnsClass1 functionName(Object parameter) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the same manner, `GenericClass2` will implement `GenericInterface<ReturnsClass2>` and `GenericClass3` will implement `GenericInterface<ReturnsClass3>`.

Your method will then look like this:

```
public <T> T myFunction (GenericInterface<T> classInstance) {
    return classInstance.functionName(parameter);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I was hoping it was possible to do this without  interfaces

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `java.util.function.Function<T, R>`.

It may look like this:

```
public <R> R myFunction (Function<Object, R> func) {
    return func.apply(parameter);
}
```

Usage:

```
ReturnClass1 rc1 = myFunction(genericClass1::functionFromClass);
ReturnClass2 rc2 = myFunction(genericClass2::functionFromClass);
```

The pros of this approach is that you don't need your generic classes to share an interface and all refactoring goes into `myFunction`. This interface is a functional interface that was introduced in Java 8, you can read more about it [in the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html). Simply what it does, it defines a function that accept a single agrument of type `T` and returns a value of type `R`.

And the wierd looking `::` is a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)